# R script to download csv file from a web page where the data link is of data:text/csv

Tags: html, r, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a R script that can download the csv file from the following website,"https://www.covidanalytics.io/projections There is a link for download data at the bottom of the page, which takes the form of "data:text/csv...". I was wondering if I can have a R script to download the file in csv format. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
IC

Comment: Wow, that's a new one to me, frustrating. They hard-coded the *data* within the href itself. All 588KB of it. The link itself appears to be generated from Dash, which means `rvest` didn't work for me. If you have the "link" text, though, remove the leading `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,`, then do `read.csv(text = utils::URLdecode(s))` (where `s` is the content after "utf-8,").

Comment: Perhaps `read.csv(text=URLdecode(sub("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,", "", s)))`.

Comment: how do i assign the s variable?

Comment: (I hope to be corrected on this ... but since the link is not to a file-backed store, it is instead generated dynamically by dash's javascript, you might need to use `RSelenium` in order to scrape the data *programmatically* **in order to create that variable `s` I referenced**. I hope somebody else finds something better.)

Comment: It will be easier if you work with their processed data in  [Github](https://github.com/COVIDAnalytics/DELPHI). That url is too long and uses too many arguments.

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure if I would correct you as such, but it is possible to get `s` - see my answer (`s` is equivalent to my `url` variable). See also my discussion of `URLdecode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are easier ways to get this data, but it *is* possible with a bit of low-level work using the httr package.

As @r2evans pointed out, this is a url-encoded csv built by Dash. To get the url, you need to request a json file containing the html page information using an xhr request. This needs all the correct headers as well as a json request in the body of the POST request:

```
library(httr)

page1 <- GET("https://www.covidanalytics.io/projections")

H <- add_headers( `Host` = "www.covidanalytics.io",
                  `User-Agent` = paste("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:77.0)", 
                                       "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0"),
                  `Accept` = "application/json",
                  `Accept-Language` = "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
                  `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate",
                  `Referer` = "https://www.covidanalytics.io/projections",
                  `Content-Type` = "application/json",
                  `X-CSRFToken` = "undefined",
                  `Origin` = "https://www.covidanalytics.io",
                  `Connection` = "keep-alive")

post_data <- paste0('{"output":"page-content.children","outputs":{"id":',
                    '"page-content","property":"children"},"inputs":',
                    '[{"id":"url","property":"pathname","value":',
                    '"/projections"}],"changedPropIds":["url.pathname"]}')

res <- httr::POST("https://www.covidanalytics.io/_dash-update-component", H,
                  body = post_data, encode = "raw")
```

'res` now contains the json response, and our url-encoded csv is deep inside it. We get this parsed content and extract the string containing the url:

```
body <- parsed_content(res)$response$`page-content`$children$props$children[[2]]
div <- body$props$children[[10]]$props$children[[1]]
url <- div$props$children$props$children$props$href
```

Now we need to cut off the `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,` part and unescape the url encoding. I actually found this was far quicker using nested `gsub`s, since my machine choked on `URLdecode`:

```
csv <- strsplit(url, ",")[[1]][2]
df <- read.csv(text = gsub("%0A", "\n", gsub("%20", " ", gsub("%2C", ",", csv))))
```

Your data is now in `df`. It's big, so I'll show it as a tibble here:

```
tidyr::as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 7,106 x 10
#>    Continent Country Province Day   Total.Detected Active Active.Hospital~ Cumulative.Hosp~
#>    <fct>     <fct>   <fct>    <fct> <fct>           <int>            <int>            <int>
#>  1 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 5651             1531              302              834
#>  2 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 5742             1514              300              848
#>  3 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 5831             1497              298              861
#>  4 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 5917             1477              296              874
#>  5 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6000             1457              293              886
#>  6 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6079             1435              291              898
#>  7 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6156             1411              287              910
#>  8 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6230             1387              284              921
#>  9 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6300             1361              280              932
#> 10 Africa    Algeria None     2020~ 6368             1335              277              942
#> # ... with 7,096 more rows, and 2 more variables: Total.Detected.Deaths <int>,
#> #   Active.Ventilated <int>
```

Comment: I suspected there had to be a way, nice.